# How to expose a IIS website outside the domain

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, iis-6, hosting

I have been programming remotely over VPN on my dev machine which is running Windows server 2003. My dev website is hosted on IIS 6 and can be accessed internally within the domain like `http://MyDevMachineName:8080`.

How do I expose the site externally so that I can access it from my local machine over internet like `http://MyDevWebsite.com`? At the same time the website should remain accessible internally.

I know changes are required in the website host headers and possibly in C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file but I am not aware of exact steps.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to make any changes to C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.
2. You'll need to port forward port 8080 from your firewall/router to the server.
3. If you want external users to connect to the web site by name then you'll need to purchase and register a domain name. You'll need to find a DNS host for your DNS records for the domain. Many registrars offer this service at no cost. You'll then need to configure the appropriate DNS records for your domain and your web site.
4. You may need to configure host headers on the web site, depending on whether or not it is the default web site.
5. Users will need to specify port 8080 when connecting to the web site, unless you configure some type of redirect from port 80 to port 8080.

Comment: so the changes are not limited to my dev box it seems. I am a developer and it's unlikely that I will have rights for performing some of those steps. So apparently I wouldn't be able to do it without some help from our system admins.